# Change text origin and direction - CSS

Tags: css

I would like to if this is possible in CSS. See, I have a text "This is my text". I know how to position it right using `float: right` or `text-align right` or `direction:rtl`. But is it possible to fix the text origin and then direction? my word should look like this;

```
                                                                 txet ym si sihT
```

floating at the right side of the page. If this can't be done with pure CSS, what are the other possibilities?

Note: I don't want a mirror image which can be done with various `transform` properties.

Comment: "This is my text" is not a word, it is a sentence. What do you need forced RTL for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>This is my text</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

output

txet ym si sihT

Comment: It is about as cross-browser as you can get in CSS. Even IE 6 supports this.